# Python: Intellisense doesn't work for Object from module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have the following code in Python which uses the `tweepy` module to interact with Twitter. The following code works perfectly fine. It gets an user from Twitter by its @name (in this case `testuser`) and prints its display-name then.

```
import tweepy

... # Initialization of the keys and tokens used below

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

user = api.get_user("ThePSF")
print(user.name)
```

The output is, like expected:

```
Python Software
```

The problem is that Intellisense in VS Code (autopep8) doesn't suggest the attributes and methods for `user` like `name`, `description`, `location` etc...

[image: Intellisense doesn' suggest anything for the tweepy.user object]

BUT Intellisense suggests me attributes and methods of `api` although I do not know why it works for that one and not for the `user` object.

[image: Intellisense does work]

> I already looked up this Github issue page but I didn't find a
>   solution
>
> https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/647

---

### What am I doing wrong such that it doesn't show me the Intellisense for the `user` object?

Answer (score 1):

You're quite possibly not doing anything wrong and tweepy is simply structured in a way that inhibits IntelliSense. Do make sure to [try the Microsoft language server](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3977) to see if that works for you.

Comment: It now shows me some more suggestions but still not the ones I was looking for (`name`, `description`, `location` etc...). Why would tweepy want to inhibit IntelliSense? And didn't you get anything out of the Github Issue I mentioned above?

Comment: It isn't that tweepy wouldn't want to inhibt IntelliSense, it just might be those attributes are dynamically produced via `__getattr__` or something, in which case it's just not possible to deduce what the potential attributes are for the object. You can try opening an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server, but do run `dir()` on the object you want IntellISense for to see if even Python sees the attributes you're after.

Comment: Ok, when I run `dir()` on my `user` object, I get 83 names back, that's fine. But why would tweepy generate them dynamically? Aren't they just always there? Or is it an issue of the Python Language Server?

Comment: Python is flexible enough to not require attributes to be defined ahead of time, so they are not necessarily there. Feel free to file a bug for the Microsoft language server as I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while running [microsoft's python language server](https://github.com/microsoft/python-language-server) on a fresh installation of windows and visual studio code.

I tried the new [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) language server instead, and it worked. The extension is available as a preview right now, so it might not be hundred percent stable, but after using it for a day I have not encountered any issues. Judging by [this blogpost from microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/announcing-pylance-fast-feature-rich-language-support-for-python-in-visual-studio-code/) this will be the preferred language server moving forward.

> Our long-term plan is to transition our Microsoft Python Language Server users over to Pylance and eventually deprecate and remove the old language server as a supported option.

Install the Pylance extension and set it as the language server by clicking yes when prompted. You can also manually set it in the `settings.json`

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```